# enabling server-side encryption when creating an AWS Glue job

Tags: aws-glue

In the AWS Glue console, I can create a job with server-side encryption enabled. However, it doesn't appear possible to do this using CloudFormation, nor with the node or python SDKs. Why is there this mismatch between what the console can do and what CloudFormation and the SDKs can do? Is there another way to enable SSE for a Glue job programmatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

enabling server side can be done programmatically by specifying the "--encryption-type" parameter with the value of "sse-s3". Here is an example of how to do it on cloud formation with YAML:

```
  etljob:
    Type: "AWS::Glue::Job"
    DependsOn: copyGlueJob    
    Properties:
      Role: !Ref gluejobrole
      AllocatedCapacity: 2
      DefaultArguments:
        "--TempDir": !Join [ "/", [ "s3:/",!Ref glueScriptsBucket , tmp/ ] ]
        "--sourcedatabase": !Join [ "_", [ "raw" , !Ref "AWS::StackName"  ] ]
        "--destinationpath": !Join [ "/", [ "s3:/",!Ref dataLakeBucketName , '' ] ]
        "--job-bookmark-option": job-bookmark-enable
        "--encryption-type": "sse-s3"
      Command: 
        Name: glueetl
        ScriptLocation: !Join [ "/", [ "s3:/",!Ref glueScriptsBucket , scripts/parquetconversion.py ] ]
```